# Before block in Rspec test run after the context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm migrating an app from rails 4 to rails 6 and the test are now broken.
I'm not so good in testing, i must improve, but I cannot understand why a before block run after the test.

```rb
    require 'rails_helper'

    RSpec.describe Admin::TrainingEmailsController, type: :controller do
      describe "GET #create", :uses_mail do
        context "with valid attributes" do
          before(:each) do
            binding.pry
          end

          describe "sends the value letter request email" do
            binding.pry
            it { expect(1+1).to eq(2) }
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

I add a couple of pry, and the when I run rspec "`sends the value letter request email`" run before the before block and so my `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last` is empty

I try with `before`, `before(:all)` and `before(:each)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't.

`describe` block is not running a test yet. It's just defining it.

only `it` or `specify` blocks, when run are executing a test. Put `binging.pry` inside the `it` block to see it:

```rb
  describe "sends the value letter request email" do
    binding.pry
    let(:mail) { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last }
    let(:request_sender) { "ValueLetters@vl.balancedview.org" }
    let(:accepted_participants_emails) do
      training.participants.accepted.
        map(&:email)
    end
    it do 
      binding.pry # <-- here
      expect(mail.to).to match(accepted_participants_emails) }
    end
  end
```